# How can I mark a contact as unable to receive text messages?

Tags: iphone, contacts, messages

A few of my contacts have mobile phones that do not send or receive text messages.  I'd like to prevent my iPhone (4S) from including those numbers as options for messaging.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change their type of phone to something that is not "mobile" or "iPhone". You can create a new type of phone if you want and name it something like "nosms".

Comment: It's not enough to not call it "mobile", it has to at least not start with "mobile"; "mobile/nosms" still has the message option, but "cell/nosms" does not.